# What is a tie delegation model in a CORBA application?

Tags: corba

What is a tie delegation model in a CORBA application? When is it
used?

Answer (score 1):

It is a different way to implement your servants. The normal approach is to use the inheritance approach, but TIE is mostly used when multiple inheritance in application code is tried to mix with CORBA. I would recommend you to use the inheritance approach.

Answer (score 0):

The tie model is used for Java implementations to get rid of inheritance, which is usual in CORBA objects.

see also http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cis888w04/cis888w04su64.html

- The tie model **frees the implementation to inherit from arbitrary interfaces**
- The tie model is an alternative to the typical inheritance model